# Hide the tab bar when displaying the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have the following code to set up and switch to the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

```
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [
        [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init
    ];
    peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    window = [[[currentView superview] superview] superview];       
    [window addSubview:[peoplePicker view]];
    [[[peoplePicker view] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"nav"];
```

The view it is switching from is controlled by a UITabBarController. I'd to prevent the tab bar from displaying while the peoplePicker is the active view, but so far I haven't had any luck. I've looked into hidesBottomBarWhenPushed, but since I can't push a navigation controller, it isn't helpful. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

on your `UITabBarController` object. This should cause the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to fill the entire window, hiding the TabBar.